# Search for text within a DTS file

Tags: sql-server

We have a large store of DTS files which I need to search through for a string of text.

Is there any utility which will allow me to do this?

Many thanks

EDIT: Prefer free/open source as I work for a charity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [SSIS-DTS Package Search](http://www.dtspackagesearch.com/)

Comment: Thanks Jim, I'll give this a try on Monday when I am back at work.

Comment: That app works great, however the licencing may be a bit steep for my company (I work for a charity). If no-one else comes up with a cheaper/free option I'll accept you answer.